# How to execute function every 6 hours?

Tags: javascript

I need to refresh my token every 6 hours so I can use an API without logging in again.

I'm trying like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
      var code = window.location.href.split("=").pop();      
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id="+appID+"&client_secret="+secretKey+"&code="+code+"&redirect_uri="+redirectUri, true);
      xhr.onload = function () {    
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      };
      xhr.send();
    }    
}, 21600);
```

Comment: And what is the problem / not working? Also, you are not using any jquery in your code.

Comment: I'm assuming the browser is going to stay open for a straight 6 hours, staying on that same page, without page transitions?

Comment: `21600` is not 6 hours

Comment: When using `POST`, you should add the data as an argument to `xhr.send` call. Also, the timer takes milliseconds, currently you're posting once per 21.6 seconds.

Comment: I don’t know how reliable it will be to set a timer for six hours. If you refresh the page it’d reset the clock. It would probably be better to check every few minutes to see if the current token is about to expire and then perform the refresh if it is.

Comment: You are keeping the page open for six hours? You should look at cronjob

Comment: Please review your concept, actually no page will stay open for 6 hours and wait until token refreshes. Send token expiration time from server(when token is created add 6 hours on server side and return timestamp), then on client side check if now is bigger than expiration timestamp, then refresh

Comment: Please consider instead responding the the http response (status code, etc) that correlates with expiration (statusCode 401??). When a response has this status kick off a new request and queue pending requests. If the result is successful retry the queue, otherwise prompt the user to login again (or whatever is appropriate?).

Comment: Consider using the URL api `var u = new URL(location)` and use the key for the parameter like: `u.searchParams.get('key')`. This will handle all of the url idiosyncrasies for you--no need to hassle with string parsing like the `location.href.split('=').pop()` that's really problematic especially long-term.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged your question with `jQuery`, so I'm assuming that you are OK with using it.
Also `21600000` is 6 hours, not `21600`.

```
setInterval(function() {
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType : "text",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
  });
}, 21600000);
```

or a little messier solution with `bind`:

```
setInterval($.ajax.bind($, {
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  dataType : "text",
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  timeout: 3000,
  success: function (data) {
      alert("SUCCESS");
      console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (e) {
      alert(e);
  }
}), 21600000);
```